# How to unpublish a gatsby page without deleting it?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I used a Gatsby starter for my static site, and one of the pages included in that starter is a demo page with all of the UI elements.

I want to keep the page (so I can copy and paste from the demo) but don't want to be publicly available. How do I "unpublish" without deleting the file?

Is there a way to tell gatsby-node.js to skip that page when generating the public facing site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a bunch of [Gatsby Node API helpers](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-api-helpers/) that you can use, one being [deletePage](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#deletePage).

If you have a page `src/pages/demo.js`, this will delete that page during creation.

```
// gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions: { deletePage } }) => {
    if (page.path.match(/^\/demo/)) {
      deletePage(page)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was easiest for me, I just added
process.env.NODE_ENV === `production` &&

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good options here, just wanna throw my hat in the ring for plugin options that prevent pages from being created in the first place:

If it is a page component, i.e inside `src/pages` folder, `gatsby` use a plugin called [`gatsby-plugin-page-creator`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-page-creator/) to generate page, and it recently accept a ignore patterns.

There's a caveat, the built-in `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` doesn't take user options, so we'd have to rename the pages folder to ignore it.

```
  root
    └── src
-        └── pages
+        └── screens  <-- rename
               └── index.js
               └── ignore-file-name.js
```

And then in gatsby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-page-creator`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/screens`,
        ignore: [`ignore-file-name.js`],
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

---

If it is a programmatically page generated from markdown or json, you might be able to ignore it in `gatsby-source-file-system`, as pointed out in this [github comment](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25#issuecomment-475893504).

The example there even ignores file based on environment, which is more useful since you can still see your reference during development, but it won't show in build.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content`,
    ignore: process.env.NODE_ENV === `production` && [`**/draft-*`]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to add a "published" attribute to the frontmatter assuming it's a markdown page that could be a true or false value. Then add logic into your `gatsby-node.js` file which looks at this to determine whether or not to run `createPage()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the file extension to something that does not indicate it is JavaScript, like `mypage.js.draft`, works for me.

Downside could be that your editor might not automatically detect that it is a JS anymore. (My VSCode still does)