# Is there a way to avoid building pages with certain paths in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

We know that Gatsby builds pages in the directory src/pages/ automatically with the path of the same name as the .js file. For example, I have a file src/pages/example.js, when I run the command `gatsby develop` in the terminal, the webpage will be available on the site “localhost:8000/example”.

However, given that I am not allowed to build the webpage with the path “/example”, is there a way to blacklist the path “/example”, stop the build/develop process whenever we try to build using a blacklisted path and report an error like “You are not allowed to build the page with the blacklist path: /example” in the terminal?

To give you more context, I now have some website built in Docusaurus running on the url “www.example-domain.com/example”. I want Gatsby to report an error when building the site on “www.example-domain.com/example” and tell the developer that this path is already in use so that the developer can change the name of example.js to other names like another-example.js.

Comment: Some ideas for you in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519931/how-to-unpublish-a-gatsby-page-without-deleting-it?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you might be able to use the [onCreatePage](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/#onCreatePage) event for this purpose.

In your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions, reporter }) => {
  
  // Page is an object which amongst other things contains the path
  if (page.path.match(/example/) {
    reporter.panic('Stop! in the name of love...')
  }
}
```

Not sure wha the best approach is as to the action there. If you print to console it might be missed. You can `process.exit(1)` or potentially rename the file. Perhaps this is enough to get you on right track.

Comment: Also the reporter helper should be accessible in the `onCreatePage` api so you could do `repoter.error()` or `reporter.panic()`. Check [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-api-helpers/#GatsbyReporter) for more.

Comment: Nice one @Z.Zlatev - I've updated answer to add the reporter.