# Why does Gatsby Source Filesystem not recognize environment only ignore during npm start?

Tags: gatsby, environment, dotenv

Reading how to exclude a directory on build I ran across this [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25) in Gatsby and it indicated to ignore a directory in `gatsby-source-filesystem` you can ignore based on `env` with:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    path: `${__dirname}/content`,
    ignore: process.env.NODE_ENV === `production` && [`**/draft-*`]
  }
}
```

[ref](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25#issuecomment-475893504) but when I try to use a similar approach with:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `designs`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/designs/`,
    ignore: process.env.NODE_ENV === `production` && [`*`],
  },
},
```

it throws a terminal error of:

> Invalid plugin options for "gatsby-source-filesystem":
>
> - "ignore" must be an array

I am bringing in `dotenv` at the top of *gatsby-config.js* with:

```js
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

and if the `env` condition is removed it works:

```js
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `designs`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/designs/`,
    ignore: [`*`],
  },
},
```

I was reading "[How to unpublish a gatsby page without deleting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519931/how-to-unpublish-a-gatsby-page-without-deleting-it)" that led me to this question. I do not have an issue with it working on `npm run build` just with `npm run develop`. In Gatsby develop is there a way to use an ignore with an env condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly the reason why but I faced the same issue with different plugins (like generating different `sitemap.xml` for different environments or stuff like that). I bypassed it by generating the variable outside the scope of the `module.exports` like:

```js
 require(`dotenv`).config({
   path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
 });
 
 let ignore= process.env.NODE_ENV === `production` ? [`*`] : [];
 
 module.exports = {
   plugins: [
     {
       resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
       options: {
         name: `designs`,
         path: `${__dirname}/src/designs/`,
         ignore: ignore,
       },
     },
   ]
```

Tweak the ternary condition to add `` process.env.NODE_ENV === `production` && [`*`] `` if needed.